# How can I run a thread after another thread has completed its actions

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to simulate a parking lot entry system that contains 2 floors of 20 spaces and 2 entries and 2 exits. I am using Threads in Java, and I have tried to use `thread.wait()` and `thread.sleep` but they don't help in making a thread run after another thread is over.

This is what I have come up with so far:

**ShardedDataThread.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SharedDataThread extends Thread {
      private SharedData mySharedData;
      private String myThreadName;
      public int L1 = 20;
      public int L2 = 20;


//Setup the thread
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
SharedDataThread(String name, SharedData sharedstuff) {
    super(name);
    mySharedData=sharedstuff;
    myThreadName=name;
}

//This is called when "start" is used in the calling method

public void run() {
     while(true){

    System.out.println("Entry or Exit?");
    String input = null;
    try {
        input = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("entry"))  {

            try {
              // Acquire the lock using the acquireLock() method
              // The thread will pause here on wait() until it gets a lock
              mySharedData.acquireLock();

               //use park method to occupy one space
              this.park(); // Increment the number of reads
              mySharedData.releaseLock(); 
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to get lock when reading:"+e);
            }
          }
          else {

            try {

                mySharedData.acquireLock();
                System.out.println(myThreadName+" is writing");
                exit(); // INCREMENT ONE SPOT

                mySharedData.releaseLock(); // releases the lock
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to get lock when writing:"+e);
            }
         }

      System.out.println("L1 has : "+L1+" "+"L2 has: "+" "+L2);

    }
 //while ends
}
//State method


    public void park() {
        if (L1>0 && L1<=20){
            L1= L1-1;   
            }

            else if (L1==0 && L2<=20 && L2>0){
                L2= L2-1;   

                }
            else if (L1==0 && L2==0){
                 System.out.println("No Spaces Left");
                }   
}

    public void exit() {
         if (L1<20) {
             L1 = L1 +1;
         } else if (L2<20) {
             L2 = L2+1;
         }  
}

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {

            SharedData mySharedData = new SharedData();



            SharedDataThread myThread1 = new SharedDataThread("Entry1", mySharedData);
            //SharedDataThread myThread2 = new SharedDataThread("Entry2", mySharedData);
            //SharedDataThread myThread3 = new SharedDataThread("Exit1", mySharedData);
            //SharedDataThread myThread4 = new SharedDataThread("Exit2", mySharedData);

            // Now start the threads executing

            myThread1.start();
            //myThread1.join();
            //myThread2.start();
            //myThread2.join();
            //myThread3.start();
            //myThread3.join();
            //myThread4.wait();
          }


}
```

**SharedData.java**

```
public class SharedData {

  private boolean accessing=false; // true a thread has a lock, false otherwise

  // attempt to acquire a lock
  public synchronized void acquireLock() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread(); 


    while (accessing) {  
      wait();
    }

    accessing = true;

  }

  // Releases a lock to when a thread is finished

  public synchronized void releaseLock() {
      //release the lock and tell everyone
      accessing = false;
      notifyAll();
      Thread me = Thread.currentThread(); // get a ref to the current thread
  }

}
```

Comment: Thread.join..........

Answer (score 1):

This never makes any sense:

```
myThread1.start();
myThread1.join();
```

It never makes any sense to start a thread and then immediately wait for it to finish.  The entire point of having threads is that different threads can be doing different things *at the same time*.

If there isn't anything else that the caller wants to do while `myThread1` is running, then there is no reason to create `myThread1`.  The caller should just do whatever it is that `myThread1` would have done at that point.

---

Don't use threads to model objects in a simulation.  Use threads to do *work*.  Usually, that means, use a *thread pool* such as `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` to perform *tasks*.

If you want your simulation to run in real time, don't use threads that `sleep()`.  Use a *scheduler* such as `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to perform *delayed* tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about the problem wrong. Don't think about waiting for a thread to do something after a thread is done. Think about doing something after some *work* is done. That means that the work has to be waitable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want me to start the second thread while the first thread is completing its actions, for example would it work if the second thread were used to exit whilst the first thread was running?

Comment: I want you to stop thinking about threads and think about work. Your problem is not "I want to start thread X when thread Y is done", it's "I want to do work X when work Y is done".